# Leaflet map -- sometimes it shows, sometimes it doesn't, any idea why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, leaflet, twitter-bootstrap-3

Firefox 24.0 and the most recent Chrome both seem to refuse to load my leaflet map...but low and below -- it loads on Safari on my Iphone (not useful, but interesting to note).

This is my first stab at Leaflet and Bootstrap...other then the .container working unpredictably when I called it from localhost...I haven't had any problems until I tried to load it onto a webpage...

I am mostly curious why this is, I haven't seen something like this before...

Thanks!

Site: [Link to Leaflet Map](https://googledrive.com/host/0BxTGtYdXPZ8QNXRwbXdhRDVHbG8/)

Any thoughts maybe?

Comment: Hey if any of my pointers have been helpful please consider to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue is probably related to cdn and security. When I open your sample site in Chrome it gives me a *warning that a script is being loaded from unauthoriced sources.*

Since FF23 these scripts are also blocked directly in the browser, and you get error messages as such:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"
```

When I allowed to load unauthorized scripts in chrome, (there is a little shield icon in the address bar) it worked without a problem!

So try to provide these scripts locally, *it might have something to do with google drive, that it is more restrictive because of javascript threats as such.*

I hope it helped, and if you think this is the solution please mark it as an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are loading leaflet.js before jquery, I get 9 js errors on the page.

One of them says:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Is leaflet dependend on jquery? Then you should load it first...

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.js"></script>    
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: fun...well I updated it to get rid of the ReferenceError...and ended up with a jQuery is not defined....accept, I have it in there...`<!-- Javascript -->
 <!-- include jQuery first!!! -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: What you could try is to load everything native, without a cdn and see if you get the same result?!?